# how to apply multiple where conditions programmatically

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ('1','NA','9'),
        ('4','2', '5'),
        ('6','4','2'),
        ('5','NA','1'),
        ('7','N/A','8'),
        ('','4','6'),
    ],
    ['id','roll','age']
)
```

I'd want to remove any rows that have any column containing `'N/A'`, `''`, `'NA'`. How to implement in Pyspark, given that the column names are unpredictable?

Comment: there doesn't seem to be a row with those exact 3 values. Do you want to remove any row with any of those values? have you tried anything?

Comment: yes if any row containing these values that  row to be removed

'''

listOfRelevantStringColumns = df.columns
remove_value_set = ['NA','n/a','']
expr = ' and '.join('(%s != remove_value_set)' % col_name for col_name in listOfRelevantStringColumns)
df.filter(expr).show()

'''

Comment: that's a OR you need, not a AND. See at the bottom, difference between OR and AND in logic : http://www.differencebetween.info/difference-between-and-and-or

Comment: @Steven how to implement the .join with multiple check values(values = 'NA','N/A','na','')

Answer (score 0):

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from functools import reduce
import operator

remove_value_set = ['NA', 'n/a', 'N/A', '']

df.where(reduce(operator.and_, [~F.col(c).isin(remove_value_set) for c in df.columns]))
```

Edit #1: updated using `reduce` and `and_` to avoid repeating column names

Comment: the column name is not predefined c_name = df.columns for i in c_name: df.where(~f.col(i).isin(remove_value_set)  this method i try but not removed the values

Comment: Took me a while, but I found the solution for that, check the updated answer